# Short story about mundane life at the end of the universe

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, apocalypse

I'm looking for a short story about the end of the world, perhaps even the end of the universe. The story follows the mundane nighttime routine of, if I recall correctly, a couple. They put the kids to bed, do the dishes, put on the radio, and wait for the end of the world. There might be something up going upstairs, a candle burning, or a door closing?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: I actually just found the story! It's "Last Night of the World," by Ray Bradbury. Thank you for your help! Should I delete the post?

Comment: No, don't delete it. You may post an **answer** and after a while you can accept it. If you don't feel like doing that, somebody else may post an answer. Anyway, leave it here for other people who may come here looking for the same story.

Answer (score 8):

**"Last Night of the World" by Ray Bradbury**

Since Phlegmatic-Farmhand hasn't written an answer despite finding one, I will.  :-)

I immediately recognized the story as "Last Night of the World" by Ray Bradbury. originally published in *Esquire* magazine, February 1951, subsequently  included in the collection *[The Illustrated Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Illustrated_Man)*. It can be read online [here](https://pubhtml5.com/jvof/embf/).

[image]